# How to determine which field has been updated?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

What's the correct way to determine which field has been changed in `update()` method on a table?

I know it's possible in `modifiedField()` via `fieldId` but that's too early.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method you are looking for is Orig()

Look in the update() method of BOMTable or BankAccountTrans

The table has a method called orig that exposes the values of the last saved state of the current record.

a good example and description can be found here
http://msdax.blogspot.co.uk/2007/07/programming-of-basic-methods-of-tables.html

```
 void update () {
     CustTable this_Orig = this.orig ();
     ;

     if (this_Orig.custGroup! = this.custGroup)
     {
       //Cust group is changing on this update
     }
     ...
```